# Track number of events written to a file in adb

Tags: android, adb

We have an android application. There is a file in adb say 'foo', in which the application is recording certain events (json data). At certain user actions, the events from 'foo' are sent to the server. So, data is being written into the file 'foo' and also data is being removed (After reading and sending it to server) from the file. I want to keep track of the total number of events that have been written to the file 'foo'. I'm only concerned about the total no.of events that are written into the file 'foo' after the application stops. Is there a way to achieve this? Kindly provide me with some pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There should be one method through which events are written in the 'foo' file. Keep a counter variable in the method and increment it with 1 each time this method is called.